# Could not mount pendrive on ubuntu 14.04 while windows normally load it

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, usb-drive

This error occurs when we want to open pendrive on Ubuntu 14.04.

Full error:

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdc: Command-line `mount "/mnt/usb-General_USB_Flash_"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Comment: And what did the advice tell you? Please include it into your message :)

Comment: Please include the `mount` command that gave you this error...